# "more generally'? sounds wrong here?

Tags: to-infinitive

I came across these two sentences in a paper and I felt wrong:

> One reason is vast literature that now exists in Cognitive Grammar and in cognitive linguistics more generally; thanks to limited accessibility, and its being situated in the Western linguistic tradition, this poses special problems for Chinese scholars.

My version goes like:

> One reason is **that** vast literature  now exists in Cognitive Grammar and in cognitive linguistics **in general**; **due to** limited accessibility, and its being situated in the Western linguistic tradition, this poses special problems for Chinese scholars.

So there should be three mistakes, right? Honestly, I'm not sure if "more generally" should be changed into "in general."

The second part of the revised version still sounds strange, so I rewrit it again:

> One reason is that vast literature  now exists in Cognitive Grammar and in cognitive linguistics in general; due to limited accessibility, and its being situated in the Western linguistic tradition, Congitive Grammar poses special problems for Chinese scholars.

Do the sentences sound OK now?

Comment: First, what you've quoted is a single sentence. Second, while the sentence has several issues, *more generally* is not one of them. Although your rephrased version is fine, you've altered the meaning of the original. (Also, by changing more than just one thing, the focus on *more general* itself has been lost.)

Comment: Technically it's a single sentence, but they are two independent clauses. This the point of using semi0colon there, right?  And could you elaborate on the "several issues" you mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: I would rephrase it this way: *One reason is [the] vast literature that now exists in [c]ognitive [g]rammar [specifically, ] and in cognitive linguistics more generally; thanks to [its] limited accessibility, and its being situated in [a] Western linguistic tradition, this poses special problems for Chinese scholars.* But the one part doesn't follow from the other. If there *is* a vast amount of literature, it makes no sense to say that there is limited access to the information.

Answer (score 1):

"More generally" is correct in this instance, because the author is trying to separate the two areas "cognitive grammar" and "cognitive linguistics" in his sentence, and apply the "more generally" assertion only to "cognitive linguistics".

A more verbose way of phrasing this would be

> One reason is vast literature that now exists in Cognitive Grammar **specifically** and in cognitive linguistics more generally;

Your modification to "in general" serves to combine the two areas together and apply the "in general" to both cognitive grammar **and** cognitive linguistics.

In terms of your second question, I agree the phrasing sounds incorrect, but I think a better way to fix the sentence would be:

> One reason is **the** vast literature that now exists in Cognitive Grammar and in cognitive linguistics more generally;

But without further context it would be hard to say if this fits.